# Using futures with boost::asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

Does anyone have a good pointer to examples which use [futures from the Boost thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) with [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)? I have an existing asynchronous library which uses callback function that I would like to provide a friendlier synchronous interface for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a concise solution without understanding the interactions with the existing asynchronous library.  Nevertheless, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346092/1053968) uses Boost.Future and Boost.Asio to implement an Active Object pattern.  When [creating a `future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures), consider examining the existing asynchronous library to determine which approach is more appropriate:

- [boost::packaged_task](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.packaged_task) provides a functor that can create a `future`.  This functor can be executed within the context of Boost.Asio `io_service`.  Some additional level of wrapping may be required to integrate with the existing asynchronous library, as well as work around rvalue semantics.  Consider using this approach if the current function calls already return the value.
- [boost::promise](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.promise) provides a lower level object which can have its value set.  It may require modifying existing functions need to accept the `promise` as an argument, and populate it within the function.  The `promise` would be bound to the handler that is provided to Boost.Asio `io_service`.  As with `boost::packaged_task`, it may require an additional level of wrapping to deal with rvalue semantics.

Finally, Boost.Asio 1.54 (currently in beta), provides first-class support for [C++ futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html).  Here is the official [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples.futures).  Even if you are unable to currently use 1.54 beta, it may be beneficial to examine the interface and implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Can you please look at this example:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp

It shows how to use `std::future` with boost asio.

The key point is to include file `use_future.hpp`:

```
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
```

Then you can write code like that:

```
std::future<std::size_t> my_future =
    my_socket.async_read_some(my_buffer, boost::asio::use_future);
```

If you need to use `boost::future` then I'd suggest to implement another variant, similar to `boost::asio::use_future`.
The file `use_future.hpp` is a good example for that.

Comment: well, such solution is actively used on on my project. And it works. Are you sure you really know the reason of blocking asio in your case?

Comment: Apparently that code in the example blocks on each future. What's the point of using futures if you just block on each one? Might as well just use blocking code in the first place...

Comment: The point of using futures with boost asio is the same as use futures with any other async operations: you trigger async operation in one place and then perform some other  operations (async operation will be running in parallel) and later - when you need the result of the async operation - you invoke get() of the future. get() might be blocking or might be not, depending on how fast the asyn operation was.