# Custom handlers in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is it possible and recommended to create custom handlers for `boost::asio`? Are there tutorials on how to do it? After searching for quite some time for it I didn't find anything (only custom allocators in `boost::asio`).

`asio` currently supports to provide callbacks, using `use_awaitable`, `use_future` for `std::future`s and more. I would like to have an implementation which works with a `boost::future` or another kind of future (like the one from `stlab`) rather than a `std::future`. Of course, I could study the `boost` source code and try to mimic it, but that seems rather cumbersome with all the portability details.

Answer (score 0):

"all the portability details" aren't so many, and you want them anyways.

Yes, study the source code e.g. for `use_future` which has an (outdated) implementation on this site:

- [boost::asio and Active Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311389/boostasio-and-active-object/16346092#16346092) which shows how to implement `boost::future` support
- see also [Using futures with boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282434/using-futures-with-boostasio?rq=1) (using futures is not the most usual approach)