# boost::asio::io_service::run in more than one thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was trying to implement the [ActiveObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) using boost::asio::io_service, but the result is not exactly as what I expected:

Below is my codes:

```
#include    <boost/asio.hpp>
#include    <chrono>
#include    <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include    <memory>
#include    <thread>
#include    <string>
#include    <functional>
#include    <ctime>
#include    <chrono>

#define SIZE 10 

class ActiveObject
{
  public:
  ActiveObject()
  {
    executionThread_.reset( new std::thread(    [&]{  service_.run();  }  ) );
  }

    virtual ~ActiveObject()
    {
      // execute all unfinished work in case this object is leaving scope.
      service_.poll();
      service_.stop();
      executionThread_->join();
      std::cout << "active object thread exited" << std::endl;
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
      // post request the io_service to invoke someImpl method and return immediately
      service_.post([=]{ someImpl();});
    }

  protected:
    boost::asio::io_service service_;

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> executionThread_;

    void someImpl() {
      std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 200 );
      std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
      std::cout << "poll thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "main thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

  ActiveObject obj;

  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    obj.doSomething(); // call is nonblocking
  }

  std::cout <<  "main thread exited " << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What I want is to run the boost::asio::io_service::run on the same thread, but it turns out not. From the log printed, the run() is also runned on the main thread. Below is the log printed:

```
main thread id: 140070853244800
main thread exited 
poll thread id: 140070832256768
poll thread id: 140070853244800
poll thread id: 140070832256768
poll thread id: 140070853244800
poll thread id: 140070832256768
poll thread id: 140070853244800
poll thread id: 140070853244800
poll thread id: 140070832256768
poll thread id: 140070853244800
poll thread id: 140070832256768
active object thread exited
```

Any idea on this? Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346092/1053968) answer may provide ideas on how to implement some of the elements in the Active Object pattern.

Answer (score 1):

At least where you do

```
service_.poll();
service_.stop();
```

you are actively making the service run on the active thread.

To mitigate, you'd say

```
service_.post([&] { service_.poll();});
service_.stop();
```

but then that `poll()` would be awful redundant. This *appears* to fix your problem:

#### **HOWEVER** there's a big problem;

Why do we even call `stop()`? `run()` just completes when all work is done, right? In fact, **`run()` may complete immediately during/after construction**. All work would be deferred to the destructor.

However, if `run()` completed, the service needed to be reset(), so **no work  might actually run ([demo live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e93acdb23748eaed)**!!!) Oops. That's a nasty race condition.

To prevent `run()` from completing "prematurely", use a `work` item: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3cac88328cfce15)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#define SIZE 10

class ActiveObject
{
public:
    ActiveObject()
        : service_(),
          work_(boost::asio::io_service::work(service_))
    {
        executionThread_.reset(new std::thread([&] { service_.run(); }));
    }

    virtual ~ActiveObject()
    {
        // execute all unfinished work in case this object is leaving scope.
        work_ = boost::none;
        executionThread_->join();
        std::cout << "active object thread exited" << std::endl;
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        // post request the io_service to invoke someImpl method and return immediately
        service_.post([this] { someImpl();});
    }

protected:
    boost::asio::io_service service_;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> executionThread_;

    void someImpl()
    {
        std::chrono::milliseconds dura(200);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
        std::cout << "poll thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    ActiveObject obj;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(200);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        obj.doSomething(); // call is nonblocking
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    std::cout <<  "main thread exited " << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
main thread id: 140312603891520
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
main thread exited 
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
poll thread id: 140312580617984
active object thread exited
```

Comment: Boost.Asio guarantees that handlers will only run within threads invoking `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()`.  If `stop()` is causing tasks to run in the calling thread, then it is a bug.  Here is a [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a739d7c6e88d02b8) demonstrating the expected behavior.

Comment: @TannerSansbury I can't reproduce it now. It might have been a stale terminal output I was consulting. I'll amend the text, thanks for the correction (done, including coliru link now).