# IO Service per core design with singleton

Tags: c++, singleton, boost-asio, mutex

I'am developing currently game server, and currently I have one design problem.

Game server have World class (it's singleton) and when i changed from single I/O service to I/O service per core, I think i should use mutex in my World class.
Because packet handler from client sometimes perform operations using World's functions.

Is there way to avoid mutex in that singleton ?

Comment: Well, don't use code which breaks things if used from multiple threads? :)

Comment: Actually, it's a good practice to instantiate your singleton before you enter multithread mode, somewhere near the start of the application. And then you should use locks where they're needed indeed. W/o knowledge of your service logic it's hard to make more precise suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Active Object pattern.

So make the World implementation an active object, in effect running all operations on its own thread.

A sample of the Active Object pattern with Boost Asio is here: [boost::asio and Active Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311389/boostasio-and-active-object/16346092#16346092)

Whether it is (performance-wise) appropriate for you to make World an active object, I cannot tell. I have a feeling you should /simply/ not access World from many threads, instead only running computation-intensive stuff in the background that you don't need locks to coordinate, or where the locking overhead isn't significant.

In my **[comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569805/boost-thread-throwing-exception-thread-resource-error-resource-temporarily-una/22574823#comment34366350_22574823)** I showed an alternative approach to dispatching jobs with a lock-free queue implementation.