# How to combine strand wrapper and priority wrapper on Boost Asio

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I'd like to use Boost.Asio's strand and prioritized wrapper in the same time.

Before I write my code, I've read the following information:

[Boost asio priority and strand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939817/boost-asio-priority-and-strand)

[boost::asio and Active Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311389/boostasio-and-active-object/16346092#16346092)

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/3531

[Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio)

I'd like to use wrapper approach, because I'd like to use various async APIs such as async_read, async_write, and async_connect.
According to the http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/3531 , it seems that the priority wrapper and strand wrapper can be combined.

So I wrote the code based on the following example:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

#define ENABLE_STRAND 1
#define ENABLE_PRIORITY 1

class handler_priority_queue {
public:
    template <typename Handler>
    void add(int priority, Handler&& handler) {
        std::cout << "add(" << priority << ")" << std::endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx_);
        handlers_.emplace(priority, std::forward<Handler>(handler));
    }

    void execute_all() {
        auto top = [&]() -> boost::optional<queued_handler> {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx_);
            if (handlers_.empty()) return boost::none;
            boost::optional<queued_handler> opt = handlers_.top();
            handlers_.pop();
            return opt;
        };
        while (auto h_opt = top()) {
            h_opt.get().execute();
        }
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    class wrapped_handler {
    public:
        wrapped_handler(handler_priority_queue& q, int p, Handler h)
            : queue_(q), priority_(p), handler_(std::move(h))
        {
        }

        template <typename... Args>
        void operator()(Args&&... args) {
            std::cout << "operator() " << std::endl;
            handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        //private:
        handler_priority_queue& queue_;
        int priority_;
        Handler handler_;
    };

    template <typename Handler>
    wrapped_handler<Handler> wrap(int priority, Handler&& handler) {
        return wrapped_handler<Handler>(*this, priority, std::forward<Handler>(handler));
    }

private:
    class queued_handler {
    public:
        template <typename Handler>
        queued_handler(int p, Handler&& handler)
            : priority_(p), function_(std::forward<Handler>(handler))
        {
            std::cout << "queued_handler()" << std::endl;
        }

        void execute() {
            std::cout << "execute(" << priority_ << ")" << std::endl;
            function_();
        }

        friend bool operator<(
            queued_handler const& lhs,
            queued_handler const & rhs) {
            return lhs.priority_ < rhs.priority_;
        }

    private:
        int priority_;
        std::function<void()> function_;
    };

    std::priority_queue<queued_handler> handlers_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
};

// Custom invocation hook for wrapped handlers.
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function&& f,
                         handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h) {
    std::cout << "asio_handler_invoke " << std::endl;
    h->queue_.add(h->priority_, std::forward<Function>(f));
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    int const num_of_threads = 4;
    int const num_of_tasks = 5;

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::strand strand(ios);


    handler_priority_queue pq;

    for (int i = 0; i != num_of_tasks; ++i) {
        ios.post(
#if ENABLE_STRAND
            strand.wrap(
#endif
#if ENABLE_PRIORITY
                pq.wrap(
                    i,
#endif
                    [=] {
                        std::cout << "[called] " << i << "," << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                    }
#if ENABLE_PRIORITY
                )
#endif
#if ENABLE_STRAND
            )
#endif
        );
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    for (int i = 0; i != num_of_threads; ++i) {
        pool.emplace_back([&]{
                std::cout << "before run_one()" << std::endl;
                while (ios.run_one()) {
                    std::cout << "before poll_one()" << std::endl;
                    while (ios.poll_one())
                        ;
                    std::cout << "before execute_all()" << std::endl;
                    pq.execute_all();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    for (auto& t : pool) t.join();
}
```

The wrappers are enabled by the following macros:

```
#define ENABLE_STRAND 1
#define ENABLE_PRIORITY 1
```

When both macros are enabled, I got the following result:

```
before run_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(0)
queued_handler()
before poll_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(1)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(2)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(3)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(4)
queued_handler()
before execute_all()
execute(4)
execute(3)
execute(2)
execute(1)
execute(0)
before run_one()
before run_one()
before run_one()
```

I expect that I got

```
[called] priority,thread_id
```

output as

```
[called] 1,140512649541376
```

but I didn't get it.

It seems that in the function `execute()`, `function_()` is called but `wrapped_handler::operator()` is not called. (The function `execute()` is called from `pq.execute_all();` in my code.)

```
void execute() {
    std::cout << "execute(" << priority_ << ")" << std::endl;
    function_(); // It is called.
}

template <typename Handler>
class wrapped_handler {
public:

    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args) { // It is NOT called
        std::cout << "operator() " << std::endl;
        handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

I traced the sequence after `function_()` is called.

The following functions are called:

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp#L191
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp#L76
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/strand.hpp#L158
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_service.hpp#L55
https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_service.ipp#L94

Then in the function `bool strand_service::do_dispatch(implementation_type& impl, operation* op)`, the operation `op` is not called but pushed into the queue int the following line:

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_service.ipp#L111

I'm not sure why the `function_()` is dispatched to strand_service. I think that strand wrapper has already been unwraped at the following point in my code:

```
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function&& f,
                         handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h) {
    std::cout << "asio_handler_invoke " << std::endl;
    h->queue_.add(h->priority_, std::forward<Function>(f));
}
```

If I enabled only priority wrapper, I got the following result.
It seems that working as I expected.

```
before run_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(0)
queued_handler()
before poll_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(1)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(2)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(3)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(4)
queued_handler()
before execute_all()
execute(4)
operator()
[called] 4,140512649541376
execute(3)
operator()
[called] 3,140512649541376
execute(2)
operator()
[called] 2,140512649541376
execute(1)
operator()
[called] 1,140512649541376
execute(0)
operator()
[called] 0,140512649541376
before run_one()
before run_one()
before run_one()
```

If I enabled only strand wrapper, I got the following result.
It seems that working as I expected too.

```
before run_one()
[called] 0,140127385941760
before poll_one()
[called] 1,140127385941760
[called] 2,140127385941760
[called] 3,140127385941760
[called] 4,140127385941760
before execute_all()
before run_one()
before run_one()
before run_one()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

> I'm not sure why the function_() is dispatched to strand_service. I think that strand wrapper has already been unwraped at the following point in my code:
>
> ```
> template <typename Function, typename Handler>
> void asio_handler_invoke(Function&& f,
>                          handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h) {
>     std::cout << "asio_handler_invoke " << std::endl;
>     h->queue_.add(h->priority_, std::forward<Function>(f));
> }
> ```

The parameter `f` is the original handler. That means priority queue wrapped and strand wrapped handler. The strand wrapper is outside. So when invokeing `f`, it is dispatched to strand_service. This process happenes in the same strand_service, so the handler isn't invoked.

To solve this problem, add `h->handler_` into the prioritized queue instead of `f` as follows:

```
// Custom invocation hook for wrapped handlers.
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function&& f,
                         handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h) {
    std::cout << "asio_handler_invoke " << std::endl;
    h->queue_.add(h->priority_, h->handler_);
}
```

`handler_` is a member variable of the class template `wrapped_handler`. It holds the handler that is not wrapped.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

#define ENABLE_STRAND 1
#define ENABLE_PRIORITY 1

class handler_priority_queue {
public:
    template <typename Handler>
    void add(int priority, Handler&& handler) {
        std::cout << "add(" << priority << ")" << std::endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx_);
        handlers_.emplace(priority, std::forward<Handler>(handler));
    }

    void execute_all() {
        auto top = [&]() -> boost::optional<queued_handler> {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx_);
            if (handlers_.empty()) return boost::none;
            boost::optional<queued_handler> opt = handlers_.top();
            handlers_.pop();
            return opt;
        };
        while (auto h_opt = top()) {
            h_opt.get().execute();
        }
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    class wrapped_handler {
    public:
        template <typename HandlerArg>
        wrapped_handler(handler_priority_queue& q, int p, HandlerArg&& h)
            : queue_(q), priority_(p), handler_(std::forward<HandlerArg>(h))
        {
        }

        template <typename... Args>
        void operator()(Args&&... args) {
            std::cout << "operator() " << std::endl;
            handler_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        //private:
        handler_priority_queue& queue_;
        int priority_;
        Handler handler_;
    };

    template <typename Handler>
    wrapped_handler<Handler> wrap(int priority, Handler&& handler) {
        return wrapped_handler<Handler>(*this, priority, std::forward<Handler>(handler));
    }

private:
    class queued_handler {
    public:
        template <typename Handler>
        queued_handler(int p, Handler&& handler)
            : priority_(p), function_(std::forward<Handler>(handler))
        {
            std::cout << "queued_handler()" << std::endl;
        }

        void execute() {
            std::cout << "execute(" << priority_ << ")" << std::endl;
            function_();
        }

        friend bool operator<(
            queued_handler const& lhs,
            queued_handler const & rhs) {
            return lhs.priority_ < rhs.priority_;
        }

    private:
        int priority_;
        std::function<void()> function_;
    };

    std::priority_queue<queued_handler> handlers_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
};

// Custom invocation hook for wrapped handlers.
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function&& f,
                         handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h) {
    std::cout << "asio_handler_invoke " << std::endl;
    h->queue_.add(h->priority_, h->handler_);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    int const num_of_threads = 4;
    int const num_of_tasks = 5;

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::strand strand(ios);


    handler_priority_queue pq;

    for (int i = 0; i != num_of_tasks; ++i) {
        ios.post(
#if ENABLE_STRAND
            strand.wrap(
#endif
#if ENABLE_PRIORITY
                pq.wrap(
                    i,
#endif
                    [=] {
                        std::cout << "[called] " << i << "," << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                    }
#if ENABLE_STRAND
                )
#endif
#if ENABLE_PRIORITY
            )
#endif
        );
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    for (int i = 0; i != num_of_threads; ++i) {
        pool.emplace_back([&]{
                std::cout << "before run_one()" << std::endl;
                while (ios.run_one()) {
                    std::cout << "before poll_one()" << std::endl;
                    while (ios.poll_one())
                        ;
                    std::cout << "before execute_all()" << std::endl;
                    pq.execute_all();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    for (auto& t : pool) t.join();
}
```

And here is an output:

```
before run_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(0)
queued_handler()
before poll_one()
asio_handler_invoke
add(1)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(2)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(3)
queued_handler()
asio_handler_invoke
add(4)
queued_handler()
before execute_all()
execute(4)
[called] 4,139903315736320
execute(3)
[called] 3,139903315736320
execute(2)
[called] 2,139903315736320
execute(1)
[called] 1,139903315736320
execute(0)
[called] 0,139903315736320
before run_one()
before run_one()
before run_one()
```