# Boost: Priority Queue which supports finding an element in O(log n) time

Tags: c++, boost

I am curious whether Boost offers Priority Queue implementation which also supports finding an element in time O(log n)?

I could achieve this functionality by using a Boost Fibonacci Heap, and store the handles in a std::map together with their index and update this information upon heap insert, but I was hoping for a heap version which already offers this functionality.

Note: I deleted the previous version of my question because it was too ambiguous.

Comment: What problems do you have with a simple `set`/`map`?

Comment: A `multiset` is a priority queue that supports finding stuff in logarithmic time.

Comment: I think it's implicit that key-order or "natural" order doesn't coincide with priority here. @tmyklebu has a point there

Comment: @sehe You can use a `(multi)set<pair<priority, item> >` or `multimap<priority, item>` or if the priority can be calculated easily from the items a `(multi)set<item>` with custom comparator.

Comment: @Csq AFAIK, a map does not support the priority queue operations in adequate time.

Comment: @user695652 the intent of my original comment was to ask what operations are slow for you

Comment: On average, depending on the "load factor" of each priority bucket and also the implementation of the sublists in the multimap, that could work just fine. Profiling would tell you

Comment: @Csq Ah sorry, well the min-key element should be accessible in O(1) time, a new element should be inserted and removed in O(\log n) time

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having (considerable?) overhead in space and insertion time, you can use a multi-index container here.

For an idea, here's an example that employs Boost Multi-Index to do a priority-queue implementing Active Object pattern on top of Boost Asio:

- [boost::asio and Active Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311389/boostasio-and-active-object/16346092#16346092)

It should be noted that Multi-Index let's you specify any number of secondary/auxiliary indices on the same container

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `(multi)set<pair<priority, item> >`
- `multimap<priority, item>`
- `(multi)set<item>` with custom comparator if the priority can be calculated easily from the items.

to store the elements.

If you need `O(1)` access for the top element you can use an own container that is backed by a set-like structure described above and stores an iterator to the first element and updates it when needed.

I'm not sure whether this solution performace-wise is better than other approaches but it can be implemented and measured fast. Most operations on sets are `O(n*log(n))`, just like on a priority queue but in overall the `set` should be slower as it is scattered in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find an element in a priority queue in less-than-linear time without sacrificing the asymptotic performance of priority queue operations is to keep track of the position of each element upon each priority queue operation.

The only library I found that provides the necessary functionality is `libpqueue`, now available here: https://github.com/vy/libpqueue.

It works by using user-defined callback functions `cmppri()`, `getpri()`, `setpri()`, `getpos()`, `setpos()`, which are called by the library each time the queue is updated.

The intended usage pattern is to define a wrapper data structure like:

```
typedef struct {
    pqueue_pri_t pri;
    void *data;
    size_t pos;
} node_t;
```

and accessor functions like:

```
static size_t get_pos(void *a) {
    return ((node_t *) a)->pos;
}

static void set_pos(void *a, size_t pos) {
    ((node_t *) a)->pos = pos;
}
```

This allows one to find the position of a node in `O(1)` time, at the expense of the overhead for creating the wrapper structure and the callback calls. If you need to find an element by name (and not by node_t pointer), you can easily use a `std::unordered_map` or similar as a backend.

`libpqueue` is standalone plain C under Apache license.